# Numpy subset matrix based on another with binary data

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `n x m` matrix `X` and a `n x p` matrix `Y` where `Y` is binary data. In the end I want a `p x n` matrix `Z` where the columns of `Z` are a function of the columns of `X` subsetting to the column entries corresponding to 1's in `Y`.

For example

```
>>> X
array([[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]])
>>> Y
array([[1, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [0, 1]])
n_x,m = X.shape
n_y,p = Y.shape
Z = np.zeros([p, n_x])
for i in range(n_x):
    col = X[:,[i]]
    for j in range(p):
        #this is where I subset col with Y[:,[j]]
        Z[j][i] = my_func(subsetted_column)
```

The iterations would produce

```
i=0, j=0: subsetted_column = [[1],[4]]
i=0, j=1: subsetted_column = [[7]]
i=1, j=0: subsetted_column = [[2],[5]]
i=1, j=1: subsetted_column = [[8]]
i=2, j=0: subsetted_column = [[3],[6]]
i=2, j=1: subsetted_column = [[9]]
```

I assume there is some way to do that nested loop in a single list comprehension. The function `my_func` also takes a long time so would be nice to parallelize that somehow.

**Edit**: I could do something like

```
for i in range(n_x):
    for j in range(p):
        subsetted_column = np.trim_zeros(np.multiply(X[:,i], Y[:,j]))
        Z[j][i] = my_func(subsetted_column)
```

But I still believe there is an easier solution

Comment: we can't help you 'parallelize' a function we know nothing about.  All we can help with in this question is reduce the looping overhead, which may be a small part of the run time.  If `my_func` is slow, then calling it nx*p times is going to be bottleneck, not the loop mechanism.

Comment: Agreed. My main question (and the title of the question) refer to looping.

Comment: maybe you could try not to parallelise the function itself, but run multiple instances of the function in parallel. Here's a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429377/parallel-processing-pool-python) on how to use `multiprocessing.Pool` for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this what you want?

```
import numpy as np

N, M, P = 4, 3, 2

a = np.random.random((N, M))
b = np.random.randint(2, size=(N, P)).astype(bool)

your_func = lambda x: x # insert proper function here
flat = [your_func(ai[bj]) for bj in b.T for ai in a.T]

out = np.empty((P, M), dtype=object)
out.ravel()[:] = flat
print(a)
print(b)
print(out)
```

Remarks:

- It is easiest to convert your masking array to `dtype bool` because this allows you to use logical indexing.
- If `your_func` returns just a number it's better not to use `dtype=object` for `out`.
- If you want to parallelise, a list comprehension is perhaps not the best thing to do, but I'm no expert on that. It's just that the loop looks like an obvious parallelisation target, since the order of iterations is irrelevant.

Sample output:

```
[[ 0.62739382  0.85774837  0.81958524]
 [ 0.99690996  0.71202879  0.97636715]
 [ 0.89235107  0.91739852  0.39537849]
 [ 0.0413107   0.11662271  0.72419308]]
[[False  True]
 [ True  True]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]]
[[array([ 0.99690996,  0.0413107 ]) array([ 0.71202879,  0.11662271])
  array([ 0.97636715,  0.72419308])]
 [array([ 0.62739382,  0.99690996,  0.0413107 ])
  array([ 0.85774837,  0.71202879,  0.11662271])
  array([ 0.81958524,  0.97636715,  0.72419308])]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help to perform the subsetting in a pre-processing loop

```
In [112]: xs = [X[y,:] for y in Y.astype(bool).T]
In [113]: xs
Out[113]: 
[array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]), 
 array([[7, 8, 9]])]
```

(`.T` is used to iterate on columns in the list comprehension; `bool` allows 'masked' selection)

Let's say, for example that `my_func` takes the mean on axis=0 for the subsets

```
In [116]: [np.mean(s, axis=0) for s in xs]
Out[116]: [array([ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5]), array([ 7.,  8.,  9.])]
In [117]: np.array(_)
Out[117]: 
array([[ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5],
       [ 7. ,  8. ,  9. ]])
```

I could combine it into one loop, but it's harder to think about:

```
np.array([np.mean(X[y,:],axis=0) for y in Y.astype(bool).T])
```

With this `xs` list, you can focus your efforts on applying `my_func` efficiently to all the columns of `xs[i]` as `np.mean(xs[i], axis=0)` does.

The double loop version of this mean

```
In [121]: p=np.zeros((2,3))
In [122]: for i in range(2):
     ...:     for j in range(3):
     ...:         p[i,j] = np.mean(xs[i][:,j])
     ...:         
In [123]: p
Out[123]: 
array([[ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5],
       [ 7. ,  8. ,  9. ]])
```

Equivalent double list comprehension

```
In [125]: [[np.mean(i) for i in j.T] for j in xs]
Out[125]: [[2.5, 3.5, 4.5], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]
```